# What is the procedure to deploy a Symbian-based Qt application on a Nokia device?

Tags: qt

I am new to Qt.

I have made a Symbian-based Qt application. Currently it's running on an emulator. I want to run it on a Nokia device.

What is the procedure to deploy it on a Nokia device?

Answer (score 3):

I think that the easiest way to do it is to follow the instructions of this paper:
http://sw.nokia.com/id/b6900606-f656-4e0e-a299-a6f585efb291/Getting_Started_with_Nokia_Qt_SDK_v1_0_en.pdf

You will need a Windows PC, download the [Nokia Qt SDK](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/e920da1a-5b18-42df-82c3-907413e525fb/Nokia_Qt_SDK.html) and the [Nokia Ovi Suite](http://www.comms.ovi.com/m/p/ovi/suite/index_en_uk.html), you will also need a way to connect the phone where you want to deploy to your development machine (bluetooth or usb cable), and a tool included in the SDK to install sis files to and debug applications in your phone from your PC, named App TRK.

Then you need to set a build target from your phone, connect your phone to the PC, start the App TRK and build from your PC. Then your application will be installed.

Everything is more detailed in the paper that I linked above.

If you want to distribute your applications through Ovi store you will have to wait a while since the installer of Qt applications is still in beta version.

Comment: the PDF link you have provided above does not exist now. Can you please update it? Thanks..

Comment: The getting started with Qt development section at Forum Nokia is the replacement for that PDF File.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Nokia SDK?if so,install TRK for Symbian OS on your phone and,start it,then connect it to PC via USB.You will get everything done in qt creator.